# Bluemix 'App staging failed' error while pushing Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, ibm-cloud

I am trying to push a Rails app. But while pushing, it's throwing the following error

> OUT ! Filed to install gems via Bundler.
>   OUT Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
>   ERR
>   ERR encountered error: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase

[image]

Please shares some ideas.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Did you try to build the gems on your local machine first? From the logs it seems an error related to Bundler not being able to build all the gems. Run "bundle (or bundler) install" within the directory in which there is the Gemfile

Comment: You need to include more of the log output for the failure so people can see what's going on